# How to execute a sqlalchecmy TextClause statement with a sqlite3 connection cursor?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a python flask app which primarily uses sqlalchemy to execute all of it's mySQL queries and I need to write tests for it using a local database and behave.

After a brief research, the database I've chosen for this task is a local sqlite3 db, mainly because I've read that its pretty much compatible with mySQL and sqlalchemy, and also because it's easy to set up and tear-down.
I've established a connection to it successfully and managed to create all the tables I need for the tests.

I've encountered a problem when trying to execute some queries, where the query statement is being built as a sqlalchemy TextClause object and my sqlite3 connection cursor raises the following exception when trying to execute the statement:

```
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not TextClause
```

How can I convert this TextClause object dynamically to a string and execute it?
I don't want to make drastic changes to the code just for testing.

A code example:
employees table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jeff Bezos |
| 2 | Bill Gates |

```
from sqlalchemy import text
import sqlite3

def select_employee_by_id(id: int):
    employees_table = 'employees'
    db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    with db as session:
        statement = text("""
                            SELECT  *
                            FROM {employees_table}
                            WHERE
                                id = :id
                        """.format(employees_table=employees_table)
                         ).bindparams(id=id)
        data = cursor.execute(statement)
        return data.fetchone()
```

Should return a row containing {'id': 1, 'name': 'Jeff Bezos'} for select_employee_by_id(1)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's really not a great idea to use one type of rdbms in production and another one in dev! Mysql's functionality, data types, and syntax are greatly different from sqlite's.

Comment: @Shadow I don't use sqlite in my dev environment, I only want to use it in my tests, and when I run the queries I currently have in my codebase with sqlite3 it responds well and as expected. The only problem is that I need to convert this TextClause to str dynamically for my tests because sqlite3 only accepts str, that's all. Do you have a suggestion on how to do it with no big changes to the codebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test your `TextClause` query then you should execute it by using SQLAlchemy, not by using a DBAPI (SQLite) cursor:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

def select_employee_by_id(id: int):
    employees_table = 'employees'
    engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
    with engine.begin() as conn:
        statement = text("""
                            SELECT  *
                            FROM {employees_table}
                            WHERE
                                id = :id
                        """.format(employees_table=employees_table)
                         ).bindparams(id=id)
        data = conn.execute(statement)
        return data.one()
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much!
EDIT: Sadly, I can't upvote your answer because my rep is too low, but I really want to thank you because you saved me alot of time and endless searching.